Syntax highlighting is broken (renders as `lang-none`) despite a correct `lang-python` specifier
I've slightly edited this question.  When I checked the final result, I noticed the Python code block was not properly highlighted. (I can't remember if it was before my edit.)
It's correctly (I think) annotated with lang-python directly after the opening ticks:
```lang-python

And it does correctly apply the Python highlighting in the preview with the correct lang-python class on the <pre> element.
In fact, upon inspection, the published post has the class lang-none associated on its pre element:
<pre class="lang-none s-code-block"><code>def h():


lang-py. Or just python to copy the language configured for the tag.

Reported over on MSE: Syntax highlighting when using a `lang-*` alias (and some "main" language codes) is broken

Me too, removing the lang- prefix works as expected for all languages

iirc, the syntax highlighting for the python code block was correct after I made my edit

the meta post that I linked in the edit summary also explicitly lists lang-python as a valid language code

@Aemyl it is supposed to be valid but is broken since an update, read the link shared by zcoop98 above.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I already read the post and gave it an upvote, I just wanted to add what I remebered
